# How to calculate Kp, Kd and Ki?

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller

The motor operates within 140 rev/min to 600 rev/min. The controller gives an output in the range 4 to 20 mA. The sensor output reading equivalent to 400 rev/min, actual reading was 404 rev/min. The change in set angular velocity of the motor can be take as a step function. How to calculate Kp, Kd and Ki of this ? 
  Error = 404 - 400
  Error = 4
  Kp = 140/4
  Kp = 35 Is it correct ? How to calculate other values Kd and Ki ?

Comment: A lot of things can effect good values for PID constants (e.g. load weight, type of material, shaft, etc... More of an art than science.

Comment: All I can suggest is [this tutorial](http://www.expertune.com/tutor.aspx)

Comment: Hopping SE sites, this may be helpful: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/167/what-are-good-strategies-for-tuning-pid-loops/340

Answer (score 1):

To tune a PID controller you need to take into account the entire system where the motor is installed.

There are [tons of rules of thumb](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=pid%20rule%20of%20thumb) that you can use, some more adequate than others depending on your application. But none of them really tailored for your particular application.

My generic suggestion for tuning a PID controller of a system that you can play with (you don't always have this luxury, but I understand you do) is:

1. Raise Kp until the system's response (even with a little overshoot) is satisfyingly fast to track (quasi-) step changes in your setpoint. This proportional component of a PID defines the 'stiffness' of your control system's response.
2. Raise Kd until the system's response is adequately damped. You don't need this if you don't have an overshoot. This derivative component defines an artificial damping for your system.
3. Raise Ki until the steady-state error (which you will have) with respect to the setpoint is corrected fast enough, without affecting the initial dynamics too much.
4. Fine tune all gains.

Change all values slowly, as too large values may cause instabilities in the system.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have no clue about mechanical control loops.
But here's how I tune thermal loops.
First forget the Derivative term, it sometimes helps, but is a distraction for your first loop.

OK now your system needs some gain.  (this depends on the entire control loop, sensor->amp->actuator. so there's no one number.)

There's then the time constant (TC) of the system.  (It may have more than one time constant, but let's keep it simple and assume one dominant TC.)  In a thermal loop the time constant depends on all sorts of things,  Heat capacity, thermal resistance/conductivity, maximum power to heater element, layout of sensor/ heater.... You can try and model your system, but in the end I measure it and then play a bit.  I measure the needed gain by cranking up the gain till the system starts to oscillate.  (This is the Ziegler–Nichols tuning method.)  You'll turn the gain down by a factor of 2 or so.  And then from the period of the oscillations you can estimate the time constant.  That goes into the integral term. You'll put these numbers into your loop.  Then you'll want to test it over it's entire range.  It's possible those numbers will cause oscillations/ringing at some other set point, and you'll have to tweak things.

Oh, Re-reading it could very well be that a mechanical system would like a P-D control loop.
(In which case ignore my answer.)

Comment: More on teh Ziegler-Nichols tuning method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziegler%E2%80%93Nichols_method